# Aborting asynchronous apex (future call) from trigger? Queuable Interface solution?

Tags: triggers, salesforce, jobs, apex

I'm currently working on something that involves iterating through a Sales Order and Sales Order Products via a trigger on the Sales Order object. I've created an Apex class that is called from the Sales Order after update trigger. The trigger passes a string (Sales Order Id) to the static method of the class. This future call method queries for Sales Order Products that belong to the Sales Order id, and makes a web service call for each item in the collection. This all works great, however I would like for this process to be more robust and handle errors more intelligently. What I would like to be able to do is abort the whole process when the method encounters something it doesn't like, let's say it identifies a product in the order it doesn't like as an example. The only process I've found that can handle aborting is via the Queueable Interface, and calling the class via System.enqueueJob(). This however doesn't help me as I cannot for the life of me figure out a way to pass any parameters to this class when System.enqueueJob() is invoked, since the class methods are static and the interface forces the process to run from the execute() method, which only takes a Context parameter. Am I going down the wrong road with this? The only other possibility I was thinking of was to just create methods for all of the subprocesses in my class and return from those if they encounter any errors and set a bool flag that can be used to skip processes afterward in the class. Sorry if this doesn't make sense, if so let me know and I'll try to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters to a Queueable job in the constructor. i.e.:

```
System.enqueueJob(new myQueueableClass(salesOrderId));
```

You need to add a constructor in your Queueable class that will accept the Sales Order Id and store it in a private variable also declared inside the Queueable class, which then can be accessed by the `execute()` method.